# covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value a

Tags: scala

I have following class:

```
case class Box[+A](value: A) {

  def set(a: A): Box[A] = Box(a)

}
```

And the compiler complain:

```
Error:(4, 11) covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value a
  def set(a: A): Box[A] = Box(a)
```

I was searching a lot about the error, but could not find something useful that 
help me to understand the error.

Could someone please explain, why the error occurs?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The error message is actually very clear once you understand it. Let's get there together.

You are declaring class `Box` as covariant in its type parameter `A`. This means that for any type `X` extending `A` (i.e. `X <: A`), `Box[X]` can be seen as a `Box[A]`.

To give a clear example, let's consider the `Animal` type:

```
sealed abstract class Animal
case class Cat extends Animal
case class Dog extends Animal
```

If you define `Dog <: Animal` and `Cat <: Animal`, then both `Box[Dog]` and `Box[Cat]` can be seen as `Box[Animal]` and you can e.g. create a single collection containing both types and preserve the `Box[Animal]` type.

Although this property can be very handy in some cases, it also imposes constraints on the operations you can make available on `Box`. This is why the compiler doesn't allow you to define `def set`.

If you allow defining

```
def set(a:A): Unit
```

then the following code is valid:

```
val catBox = new Box[Cat]
val animalBox: Box[Animal] = catBox // valid because `Cat <: Animal`
val dog = new Dog
animalBox.set(dog) // This is non-sensical: if `set` mutates `animalBox`, it also mutates `catBox` to no longer contain a `Cat` but a `Dog`
```

The last line is obviously a problem because `catBox` will now contain a `Dog`! The arguments of a method appear in what is called "contravariant position", which is the opposite of covariance. Indeed, if you define `Box[-A]`, then `Cat <: Animal` implies `Box[Cat] >: Box[Animal]` (`Box[Cat]` is a supertype of `Box[Animal]`). For our example, this is of course non-sensical.

One solution to your problem is to make the `Box` class immutable (i.e. to not provide any way to change the content of a `Box`), and instead use the apply method defined in your `case class` companion to create new boxes. If you need to, you can also define `set` locally and not expose it anywhere outside `Box` by declaring it as `private[this]`. The compiler will allow this because the `private[this]` guarantees that the last line of our faulty example will not compile since the `set` method is completely invisible outside of a specific instance of `Box`.

If for some reason you do not want to create new instances using the apply method, you can also define `set` as follows.

```
def set[B >: A](b: B): Box[B] = Box(b)
```

Comment: What does this `Cat <: Animal => Box[Cat] >: Box[Animal]` mean?

Comment: If you define `A` as contravariant (`Box[-A]`), then `Box[Cat]` becomes a supertype of `Box[Animal]`, which is the opposite of variance (`Box[+A]`). I clarified this part of my answer.

Comment: How can `Box[Cat]` become a supertype of `Box[Animal]`? The real world a cat can not be a supertype of animal.

Comment: What is a contravariant position?

Comment: @zero_coding Indeed `Box[Cat] >: Box[Animal]` makes no sense in that particular example. But it will become true if you define `A` as contravariant (define it as -A). All the argument of methods (like `a` in the case of your `set(a: A)` are considered to appear in "contravariant position", meaning their type `A` can only be contravariant (defined as `-A`) or invariant (no '+' or '-').

Comment: It is almost clear. Can you please provide a full example of `Dog` and `Cat` above.

Comment: It's a simple hierarchy. It's just an example, and doesn't do much to the explanation. I added that to the answer.

Comment: @Adelin Fair enough. I guess I just needed an intro, and also wanted to point out that the compiler was doing a decent job at informing you.

Comment: @francoisr your answer is awesome, sometimes statements like catch my attention ;)

Comment: @francoisr This is a very good explanation.  I was trying to write an def exists(a: A) method for a covariant type and it refused to compile.  Your answer helped me figure it out!  Thank you!!

Comment: @francoisr Why "animalBox.set(dog)" is non-sensical? `val animalBox: Box[Animal]` is declared as box containing Animal, both dog and cat are animals. Setting animmalBox.set(dog) won't change catBox's value, since value is immutable. Set returns just new Box

Comment: I believe you are confusing two different things: the immutability of a *reference to an object*, and the immutability of the *object itself*. Declaring `a` as a `val` makes it impossible to change `a` so that it refers to another object, but it **does not** make the object itself immutable! Yes, returning a new `Box` in `set` is completely valid, this is what I suggest at the end of my answer. The `set` referred to in the middle the start of my answer is the one proposed by the author which suppposes a mutable `Box`. I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score 32):

Others have already given an answer why the code doesn't compile, but they haven't given a solution on how to make the code compile:

```
> case class Box[+A](v: A) { def set[B >: A](a: B) = Box(a) }
defined class Box
> trait Animal; case class Cat() extends Animal
defined trait Animal
defined class Cat
> Box(Cat()).set(new Animal{})
res4: Box[Animal] = Box($anon$1@6588b715)
> Box[Cat](Cat()).set[Animal](new Animal{})
res5: Box[Animal] = Box($anon$1@1c30cb85)
```

The type argument `B >: A` is a lower bound that tells the compiler to infer a supertype if necessary. As one can see in the example, `Animal` is inferred when `Cat` is given.

Answer (score 7):

Try to understand what it means for your `Box[+A]` to be covariant in `A`:

It means that a `Box[Dog]` should also be a `Box[Animal]`, so any instance of `Box[Dog]` should have all the methods a `Box[Animal]` has.

In particular, a `Box[Dog]` should have a method

```
set(a: Animal): Box[Animal]
```

However, it only has a method

```
set(a: Dog): Box[Dog]
```

Now, you'd think you can infer the first one from the second, but that's not the case: I do you want to box a `Cat` using only the second signature? That's not doable, and that's what the compiler tells you: a parameter in a method is a **contravariant** position (you can only put contravariant  (or invariant) type parameters).

Comment: This is crazy, I picked the exact same classes as you did for my example, written at the same time!

Comment: @francoisr Not that crazy, if you look at ~ 90% of examples explaining covariance and contravariance, they use the animals/zoo analogy.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yeah, I guess that's the first intuitive explanation that many people get when being introduced to the concept.

Answer (score 6):

in addition to the other answers i'd like to provide another approach:

```
def set[B >: A](x: B): Box[B] = Box(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically you cant put `A`s in if `A` is covariant, you can only take it out (ex: returning `A`). If you wish to put `A`s in, then you would need to make it `contravariant`.

```
case class Box[-A](value: A)
```

Do you want to  do both, then just make it invariant

```
case class Box[A](value: A)
```

The best is to keep it covariant and get rid of the setter and go for an immutable approach.