# parameterized type checking in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to be able to assert the type of a parameterized List in Scala. For e.g. I have the following types:

```
class Animal
class Cat extends Animal
class Dog extends Animal
```

And I instantiate lists as follows:

```
val l1 = List(new Cat())
val l2 = List(new Dog())
val m = l1 ::: l2
```

When I try to assert the type of list `m` using the `scalatest` Matchers, I am only able to assert the generic type, not the parameterized type.

```
import org.scalatest.Matchers._

m shouldBe a [List[_]]
```

What I actually want to do is to assert that `m` is of type `List[Animal]` and **NOT** of type `List[Cat]` or `List[Dog]`

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Does not the compiler already proves that for you? Or do you have a `List[Any]`?

Comment: `scalatest.Matchers` appears to be runtime so it can't verify types erased by type erasure.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assert the actual type parameter in run time because of type erasure. And even if you circumvented the type erasure with somethinglike `new MyList[Cat]{/** saves the actual type parameter in anonymous class definition */}` it would make little sense since `List[Cat]` ***IS*** actually a `List[Animal]` in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

Type erasure will prevent you from checking the type parameter at runtime. This is because any `List[T]` becomes a `List[Any]` at runtime (the actual value of `T` is "erased").

However, as pointed out by others, the unit test you are writing is not needed because the compiler will automatically infer the type of `m` to be `List[Animal]`. This is because `List` is declared as *covariant* (the `+` in the `List[+T]` definition).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43180701/2174693) for more details about covariance.