# Covariance and Contravariance in Scala

Tags: scala, covariant, contravariant

I have a confusion in understanding covariance type being restricted in method parameters. I read through many materials and I am unable to get them the below concept.

```
class SomeThing[+T] {
   def method(a:T) = {...}   <-- produces error
}
```

In the above piece of code, a is of type T. Why can we not pass subtypes of T? All the expectations of method on parameter x, can be fulfilled by subtype of T perfectly.

Similarly when we have contravariant type T (-T), it can not be passed as method argument; but it is allowed. Why I think it can not be passed is: for e.g, say **method** invokes a method (present in object a)
on **a** which is present in T. When we pass super type of T, it may NOT be present. But it is allowed by compiler. This confuses me.

```
class SomeThing[-T] {
   def method(a:T) = {...}   <-- allowed
}
```

So by looking at the above, it is covariant that should be allowed in method arguments as well as in the return type. Contravariant can not be applied.

Can someone please help me to understand.

Comment: Got 30 minutes? [Here's a very recent video](https://youtu.be/aUmj7jnXet4) on this very topic.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing about variance is that it affects how the class looks **from the outside**.

**Covariance** says that an instance of `SomeThing[Int]` can be treated as an instance of `SomeThing[AnyVal]` because `AnyVal` is a superclass of `Int`.

In this case your method

```
def method(a: Int)
```

would become

```
def method(a: AnyVal)
```

This is clearly a problem because you can now pass a `Double` to a method of `SomeThing[Int]` that should only accept `Int` values. Remember that the actual object does not change, only the way that it is perceived by the type system.

**Contravariance** says that `SomeThing[AnyVal]` can be treated as `SomeThing[Int]` so

```
def method(a: AnyVal)
```

becomes

```
def method(a: Int)
```

This is OK because you can always pass an `Int` where `AnyVal` is required.

If you follow through the logic for return types you will see that it works the other way round. It is OK to return covariant types because they can always be treated as being of the superclass type. You can't return contravariant types because the return type might be a subtype of the actual type, which cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: `
  class A
  class B extends A
  class C extends B
  
  abstract class Box[-T] {
     def set(x : T) :Unit
  }
  
  val x = new Box[B] {
    def set(b:B) = Console println "B"
  }
  
  val y  = new Box[A] {
    def set(a:A) = Console println "A"
  }
  
  val z  = new Box[C] {
    def set(c:C) = Console println "C"
  }  

  x.set(new A)   <-- Type error
`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your valuable time and I apologize for my delayed reply. I seem to be getting an idea now..  Can you please have a look at the above code.. As per the definition of contravariance (super class instances will be accepted), my last statement should be accepted; but it is thrown with type error.

Comment: But at the same time, if I give x.set(new C), it is accepted which means that basically we are providing subtype only.

Comment: Since this question is closed it is best to ask this as a new question rather than trying to extend this question.

Comment: Hi @Tim, great explanation, I had the same kind of doubt. Can you please elaborate with an example the statement you made "f you follow through the logic for return types you will see that it works the other way round" or please point me to some resource which will clear this doubt on return types. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are attacking the problem backwards. The fact that you can't have `a:T` as an argument of a method if `T` is covariant comes as a constraint because otherwise some illogical code would be completely valid

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B

val myBThing = new SomeThing[B]
```

Here, `myBThing.method` accepts a `B`, and you are right that we can pass it anything that extends `B`, so `myBThing.method(new C)` is completely fine. However, `myBThing.method(new A)` isn't!

Now, since we've defined `SomeThing` with a covariant, I can also write this

```
val myAThing: SomeThing[A] = myBThing // Valid since B <: A entails SomeThing[B] <: Something[A] by definition of covariance
myAThing.method(new A) // What? You're managing to send an A to a method that was implemented to receives B and subtypes!
```

You can see now why we impose the constraint of not passing `T` as a parameter (parameters are in a "contravariant position").

We can make a similar argument for contravariance in the return position. Remember that contravariance means `B <: A` entails ``SomeThing[A] <: Something[B]`.

Assume you're defining the following

```
class A
class B extends A
class SomeThingA[-T](val value: T) // Compiler won't like T in a return type like myThing.value

// If the class definition compiled, we could write
val myThingA: SomeThing[A] = new SomeThing(new A)
val someA: A = myThingA.value
val myThingB: SomeThing[B] = myThingA // Valid because T contravariant
val someB: B = myThingB.value // What? I only ever stored an A!
```

For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180310/covariant-type-a-occurs-in-contravariant-position-in-type-a-of-value-a/43180701#43180701).

Comment: Hi francoisr, thanks for the reply and apologies for the delay. I have another question which I commented in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `class SomeThing[T]`, placing a `+` or `-` before the `T` actually effects the class itself more than the type parameter.

Consider the following:

```
val instanceA = new SomeThing[A]
val instanceB = new SomeThing[B]
```

If `SomeThing` is invariant on `T` (no `+` or `-`) then the instances will have no variance relationship.

If `SomeThing` is covariant on `T` (`[+T]`) then the instances will have the same variance relationship as `A` and `B` have. In other words, if `A` is a sub-type of `B` (or vice versa) then the instances will reflect that same relationship.

If `SomeThing` is contravariant on `T` (`[-T]`) then the instances will have the opposite variance relationship as `A` and `B` have. In other words, if `A` is a sub-type of `B` then `instanceB` will be a sub-type of `instanceA`.

But the variance indicator *does* effect how the type parameter can be used. If `T` is marked `+` then it can't be placed in a contravariant position and, likewise, if marked `-` then it can't be placed in a covariant position. We bump up against this most often when defining methods.

Scala methods are very closely related to the Scala function traits: `Function0`, `Function1`, `Function2`, etc.

Consider the definition of `Function1`:

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef
```

Now let's say you want to pass a function of this type around.

```
def useThisFunc(f: A => B):Unit = {...}
```

Because a `Function1` is contravariant on its received parameter and covariant on its result, all of the following are acceptable as a `useThisFunc()` parameter.

```
val a2b       : A => B             = ???
val supa2b    : SuperOfA => B      = ???
val a2subb    : A => SubOfB        = ???
val supa2subb : SuperOfA => SubOfB = ???
```

So, in conclusion, if `SomeThing` is covariant on `T` then you can't have `T` as a passed parameter of a member method because `FunctionX` is contravariant on its parameter types. Likewise, if `SomeThing` is contravariant on `T` the you can't have `T` as member method return type because `FunctionX` is covariant on its return type.

Comment: Hi jwvh, thanks for your valuable time in providing the answer. I apologize for my delay.